# defined proto2 message-type necessary for protobuf-net serialization?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

```
protobuf-net v2.1.0 ( latest available as NuGet package ) 
Visual Studio 2015 v14 
C#
```

I'm not using `protogen.exe` to generate my classes from message-type defs

Because I have additional requirements, I wrote my own generator which writes classes such as :

```
[Serializable]  
public partial class MyType: ProtoBuf.IExtensible                                   
{                                                                                               
  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"RegistrationDate", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")]                                                          
  public DateTime RegistrationDate;                                                                         

  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name = @"RegistrationId", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]                                            
  public long? RegistrationId;
```

But when I attempt to serialize :

```
var  myObject = new MyType(RegistrationDate="2016-01-01",RegistrationId=1);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, myObject );
```

`protobuf-net` throws exception :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   protobuf-net.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Type is not expected, and no contract can be
>   inferred: MyNamespace.MyType

Apparently `protobuf-net` is expecting the class declaration to be decorated with a proto contract attribute :

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyTypeProto")]   
public partial class MyType: ProtoBuf.IExtensible                                   
{
```

However since I'm using types such as `DateTime` and `int?` I don't believe it's possible for me to create a compatible `proto2` message-type.

How to structure my classes so that `protobuf-net` can successfully serialize ?

**UPDATE** : If I add the `[Protobuf.ProtoContract]` attribute then I can serialize/deserialize with no exceptions thrown, but my deserialized object has lost all values ( all fields are null ) :

```
[Serializable]  
[Protobuf.ProtoContract]
public partial class MyType: ProtoBuf.IExtensible                                   
{                                                                                               
  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"RegistrationDate", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")]                                                          
  public DateTime RegistrationDate;                                                                         

  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name = @"RegistrationId", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]                                            
  public long? RegistrationId;

  var  myObject = new MyType(RegistrationDate="2016-01-01",RegistrationId=1);
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, myObject );
  var deserialized = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<MyType>(stream);
  // deserialized.RegistrationDate is null
  // deserialized.RegistrationId is null
```

Answer (score 1):

All it is asking for is for you to tell it that your type really is intended for protobuf serialization; so:

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]   
public partial class MyType ...
```

The name is entirely optional. Indeed, *most* uses of protobuf-net are code-first rather than schema-first (or even schema-ever), so I would wager that it is *unusual* to have an explicit name.

As a side note, though; `DateTime` and `int?` can both be expressed in `.proto` (although the `int?` is a lot cleaner than the `DateTime` - it just becomes an `optional` field, *if* you choose to generate the schema from the type model, which you don't need to).

It doesn't acknowledge `[Serializable]` because that means something quite different and isn't even available on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks Marc. But how can DateTime and int? be allowed in proto2 ? I thought proto3 Timestamp and IntValue types were introduced specifically to remedy these deficiencies of proto2.

Comment: @BaltoStar I didn't say it used proto 3's `Timestamp` ;) And `optional int` is fine in proto2; the problem is that proto3 removes "optional" from the syntax (but: doesn't change the wire format)

Comment: Ok here's my latest understanding : for pure .NET implementations ( .NET on both sides of wire ) protobuf-net doesn't require message-type contracts -- at least not as explicitly expressed in .proto files. Indeed such contracts potentially can add complexity unnecessarily and cause confusion ( e.g. when types are required that are unsupported by the proto version ). Better to let the language object-model express the contract implicitly.  Correct ?

Comment: If for sake of better documentation of my contracts, I do want to create proto2 message-types that include type DateTime -- then for protogen.exe to work properly I need to include bcl.proto , correct ?

Comment: @BaltoStar yar, the `DateTime` thing is really intended for .net-.net; if you want better external support, I would recommend a `ulong` shim with (for example) unix time

Comment: I'm pure `.net - .net` and for `DateTime` I'm using the `private long` trick ( OPTION 2 ) but i find that serializations of classes generated from `.proto` by `protogen.exe` are not equal to serializations of my generated classes ( i'm comparing the serialized `byte[]` ).  this is true even though the `proto` member definitions appear to be identical for all members except for those of type `DateTime`.  what could account for this ?  I assume that `protobuf-net` serialization is deterministic ?

Comment: @BaltoStar I'd  really need to see examples; default values would  be my first guess - there's a global flag to disable to implicit zero-default behaviour